# Selenium, Java: Input value into a textbox on Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, selenium, safari

The only way i can input text into a field is using `Actions`, in Chrome. However, the same does not work on `Safari` and `Firefox`.

The code for intput in the application looks like this:

```
<div id="5712825281899484" class="location-input ace_editor ace-tm">
<textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="opacity: 0; height: 16px; width: 7.2px; left: 45px; top: 0px;"/>
<div class="ace_gutter">
<div class="ace_layer ace_gutter-layer ace_folding-enabled" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 180px; width: 41px;">
<div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height: 16px;">1</div>
</div>
<div class="ace_gutter-active-line" style="top: 0px; height: 16px;"/>
</div>
<div class="ace_scroller" style="left: 41px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="ace_content" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 444px; height: 180px; margin-left: 0px;">
</div>
```

Below is the code I have used to identify the input, and this works in Chrome:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='ace_content']//div[2] /child::div[@class='ace_active-line']")
    WebElement txtLocation;
```

I have used **Actions** in Chrome, whhere I am able to input the values:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.moveToElement(txtLocation);
action.click();
action.sendKeys(location).build().perform();
```

In firefox, the "Actions" do not work: selenium just continues executing without inputting the text and does not report the error.

However, in safari when I use "`Actions`" it gives me this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown command: {"id":"60ej2zi96iqs","name":"mouseMoveTo","parameters":{"element":":wdc:1455640284141"}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
```

**JAVASCRIPT**
I have also tried javascriptexecutor in both Safari and Firefox, but still not luck. This is what the code looks like in javascript:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
tempWebElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ace_layer ace_text-layer']"));
jsExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ace_line').value = '"+ location + "';");
```

The above code does not input the text, when running in Selenium it does not throw any error.

Have spent alot of time trying to sort this out. Any help will be usefull.

```
Selenium version: 2.48.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String xpath = "//div[@class='ace_content']//div[2] /child::div[@class='ace_active-line']";
String inputValue = //whatever you want to input

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.findElement(by.xpath(xpath)).sendKeys(inputValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its the issue with firefox browser because Firefox automatically gets updated to the latest version. So I would suggest you to Uninstall the latest browser version and install the Firefox old version like 38.0.